# What's the "hierarchy" of a typical HTML document?

Tags: html

I'm hoping to clarify what the typical hierarchy or levels of an HTML document are, starting with the upper-most "view." A typical HTML document might include:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head> </head>
  <body> Actual content here </body>
</html>
```

In my mind, you have the browser window, and inside that window, the above HTML document renders and fills up the entire space allotted by the window. If I were to have a script tag that referred to a window like in:

```
<script>
      var canvasEl = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
      canvasEl.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvasEl.height = window.innerHeight;
      new Asteroids.GameView(canvasEl).startMenu();
</script>
```

Does the "window" here refer to the browser window? If so, then would it be correct to assume that you can group the view from top to bottom as browser window -> HTML -> head/body, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've stated the `window` is the outer most object, as in your browser window.

Inside this is your `document` (`window.document`).

The `document` is where you can then obtain DOM elements such as head, body etc.

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")
```

---

The following article explains the difference between `window` and `document` in a bit more detail:

http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/

---

CSS Tricks details the typical structure of a HTML5 document:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure/

---

So in short you were close with your hierarchy, however you missed out the `document`.

> window > document > head/body etc

Answer (score 0):

The structure of an archive, i.e., the semantic structure of what is in the middle of `<body>` and `</body>`, is crucial to showing the page to the client. HTML4 utilizes the idea of areas and sub-segments of an archive to depict its structure. An area is characterized by a (`<div>`) component with heading components (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, or `<h6>`) inside of it, characterizing its title. The connections of these components prompts the structure of the report and its blueprint.